# HTML email is not working, Plain text Email working in CI

Tags: php, email, smtp, codeigniter-3

I am sending an Email in CodeIgniter Email library with GOOGLE SMPT from my subdomain with following configuration.

```
$this->load->library('email'); 
$config['protocol']  = 'SMTP';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'email@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'passowrd';
$config['smtp_port'] = '587';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['newline'] = '"\r\n"';

$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('info@domain.com', 'Smarty');
$this->email->to('email@gmail.com');
            
$subject=addslashes('Order Placed');
$this->email->subject($subject);
$data['data']  = $somedata;
$this->email->message(render_emailview('email',$data));
$bool=$this->email->send();
```

When i send an Email i received following message in inbox.

[image]

But when i send plain text email then it works.

**Can any one tell me is there any configuration required to send email?**

Comment: `$config['newline'] = '"\r\n"';` doesn't look right, that should probably be `$config['newline'] = "\r\n";` instead.

Comment: `$sub=addslashes('Order Placed'); eval("\$subject= \"$sub\";");` - what on earth is the purpose of that supposed to be ... ?!?

Comment: @CBroe I correct this `$config['newline'] = "\r\n";` now i received blank screen means an empty email

Comment: What happens when you leave it at the default value?

Comment: @CBroe when i remove this line `$config['newline'] = "\r\n";` again it showing message which i posted in image in my question

Comment: Option `CRLF` also exists, maybe you need to specify that one as well, or instead.

Comment: I already tried crlf `$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";` but same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254849/discussion-between-hamza-zafeer-and-cbroe).